# TalkBack decimal announcements

Tags: android, decimal, talkback, accessibilityservice

I'm having a problem with Talkback. In my string I have the following number.

1,827

it's a Dutch number so the number means:
**1 euro and 82,7 cents.**

But Talkback is saying: 
**18 hundred and 27 euro.**

So this problem only occurs when I have a number with more than 2 decimals. How to fix this issue?

---EDIT---

When I'm reading this page: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/62397/reading-out-decimal-numbers-in-english

it seems I must pronounce the number **1,827** as the following:

**one point eight two seven** instead to act if it is a number. How to do this?

---EDIT---

I included the following:

```
 StringTokenizer stringTokenizer = new StringTokenizer(value, ".");
    String currencyBeforeComma = null;
    String currencyAfterComma = null;

    while (stringTokenizer.hasMoreTokens()) {
        currencyBeforeComma = stringTokenizer.nextToken();
        currencyAfterComma = stringTokenizer.nextToken();
    }

    result = currencyBeforeComma + " point " + currencyAfterComma;
```

So now its pronouncing: **one point eighthunderd twentyseven**. So this is still now what i want.

---EDIT---

```
String value = 1,827;        
String result = "";
        for (Character chars : value.toCharArray()) {
            result = result + chars + " ";
        }
        String replace = result.replace(getResources().getString(R.string.accessibility_decimal_separator), getResources().getString(R.string.accessibility_decimal_separator_text));
        return replace;
```

This is what i did. I created a whitespace for every char in the value string and for the , or . I replaced it with a comma or point text.

This works for now but it isn't a clean solution. If anybody else has a better solution, please share

Comment: Is it correct that I only see comma not decimal point and your requirement is that only.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_mark the Netherlands is using the Arabic numerals. So the comma is the decimal point.

Answer (score 0):

Try this and modify your as per your requirement

```
TextView currencylbl = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.currencylbl);
        boolean countryCurrency = true;
        String currency = "1,827";
    if(countryCurrency==true && currency.contains(",")){

            StringTokenizer stringTokenizer = new StringTokenizer(currency, ",");
            String currencyBeforeComma = null;
            String currencyAfterComma = null;

            while (stringTokenizer.hasMoreTokens()) {
                currencyBeforeComma = stringTokenizer.nextToken();
                currencyAfterComma = stringTokenizer.nextToken();
                currencylbl.setText(currency);
            } 

            Double double1 = Double.parseDouble(currencyAfterComma);
            double1 = Double.parseDouble(currencyBeforeComma)+double1/1000;
            currencylbl.setContentDescription(double1+"");
        }
```

countryCurrency refers to particular Country currency boolean. 
Also modify as per your requirement.

```
            Double double1 = Double.parseDouble(currencyAfterComma);
            double1 = Double.parseDouble(currencyBeforeComma)+double1/1000;
            currencylbl.setContentDescription(double1+"");
```

xml is

```
<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/currencylbl"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    />
```

Comment: Will try this tomorrow :)

Comment: may I know what is the issue?

Comment: its pronouncing the same default behavior. See my second edit for what i did extra to try to fix it.

Comment: @Dennis Their are different accessibility "providers". The built in Google and Samsung. I have tested my answer.

Comment: Please try : Double double1 = Double.parseDouble(currencyAfterComma); -------
double1 = Double.parseDouble(currencyBeforeComma)+double1/1000; -------
currencylbl.setContentDescription(double1+"");

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88556/discussion-between-tauqir-and-dennis-anderson).

Comment: String textSpeech= currency.replace(",", " point ");      

currencylbl.setContentDescription(textSpeech);